# How to merge words of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to break the line by commas and merge each word with each other. The file is in csv format and looks like this:

```
babydoll,baby doll    
cami,camisole,cani    
halter,halter top
```

The code I'm currently using:

```
import collections
file = 'C:\\Users\\Shashank\\Documents\\Codes\\new.csv'
new_set = set()
with open (file, 'r') as f:
     s = f.read().split(",")
     print (s, end = "\n")
```

Output SHOULD BE:

```
['"babydoll baby doll', 'baby doll babydoll'"\n"'cami camisole', 'camisole cami', 'cani cami camisole'"\n"'halter halter top', 'halter top halter"\n']
```

Output which I got:

```
['"babydoll', 'baby doll"\n"cami', 'camisole', 'cani"\n"halter', 'halter top"\n']
```

I want to create words by adding the word which is next to by splitting `","`. For example: I have a string of words in row 1 `t1,t2,t3`, 
words should be:

```
t1 + t2, t1+3, t2 + t1, t3 + t1, t3 + t1
```

I already posted the ideal output at the top

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Cut him slack guys, new user. He has the code in the post, it was all commented.

Comment: @ShashankSahu Is that output correct? How are you getting it, is there some logic to it?

Comment: @mu無 this isn't the OP's first ever post rather it was their 5th post, it should have been obvious that the question was incorrectly formatted once they posted it. It shows poor effort on their part to not correct this

Comment: @mu無 I posted 2 outputs the one should be is I am trying for and the one which I got is through the code which I wrote, now I don't know how should I merge it.

Comment: @EdChum sorry for the inconvenience and I should take care of my side.

Comment: @EdChum Well I would like to differ. If he is never taught or shown the right way, he will never learn. If it was obvious that the question was incorrectly formatted, I believe the right course of action would be to give OP the benefit of doubt and help edit the post rather than use the close hammer. But YMMV.

Comment: @mu無 Thanks for the support. Do tell me if something  I should edit.

Comment: Regardless of the formatting, I don't understand what is actually being asked. E.g. it's unclear what the intended transformation of input to output actually is.

Comment: E.g. what is the logic of turning `"t1,t2,t3"` into the 5 items `t1 + t2, t1+3, t2 + t1, t3 + t1, t3 + t1`. Why is there a doublequote in `"babydoll`? What is the meaning of `'baby doll babydoll'"\n"'cami camisole'` (it seems like a syntax error).

Comment: @TomDalton in a single row of csv I have -> Tom,dick,harry.    Now I have to merge it with each other like:  tom dick,tom harry after this I have to take the middle value dick tom,dick harry      and then the third value harry tom,harry dick.

Comment: I have to create a new word but I don't know how to merge it.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [`itertools combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: Probably itertools.permutations since for "a,b" he wants "a b" and "b a".

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do is but I suggest you take a look at Python's [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=permutations#itertools.permutations) function.

For each line of your CSV file, split the line on commas and then pass the resulting list to this function to give you all unique pairs:

```
from itertools import permutations            

output = []  

with open('new.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    for row in  f_input.read().splitlines():
        for p in permutations(row.split(','), 2):
            output.append(' '.join(p))

print(output)
```

For the example you have given, this would create a list containing:

```
['babydoll baby doll', 'baby doll babydoll', 'cami camisole', 'cami cani', 'camisole cami', 'camisole cani', 'cani cami', 'cani camisole', 'halter halter top', 'halter top halter']
```